# LEFT JOIN on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a problem getting to work a query with an outer join as expected.

The data is:

```
TABLE a:

    id
    1
    2
    3

TABLE b:

    id  aid
    11  1
    12  2

TABLE c:

    id  bid
    21  11
    22  12
```

The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    a
    LEFT JOIN
    b
    ON a.id = b.aid
    INNER JOIN c
    ON b.id = c.bid
```

I need to get all `a` and where possible the `b` and `c`, like this:

```
a.id    b.id    b.aid   c.id    c.bid
1       11      1       21      11
2       12      2       22      12
3       null    null    null    null
```

The `INNER JOIN` just being an extension of `b` when the prior `LEFT JOIN` matched.

Instead, I get:

```
a.id    b.id    b.aid   c.id    c.bid
1       11      1       21      11
2       12      2       22      12
```

Without the second `INNER JOIN` I get, as expected:

```
a.id    b.id    b.aid
1       11      1
2       12      2
3       null    null
```

> There seems to be a different definition of joins between Oracle and MS SQL Server. (TURNS OUT TO BE WRONG)

I can't figure out how to write the query to obtain the expected result.

Comment: There no difference in inner and left join between Sql Server and Oracle

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if SQL Server returned anything different for that. You need an outer join for the second join as well

Comment: The (second) inner joi can't join  a null value  for b.id  ..so your expection seems not correct .. oracle  and ms sql work in same way ..for join

Comment: Probably I remember wrong. But how else can I write this query to obtain the expected result? Maybe I should rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour and SQL Server will return exactly the same result. See an online example here: http://rextester.com/EEGBZ41105

Because you are doing an inner join between b and c, this essentially voids the outer join between a and b.

If you look at the last row of the expected output:

```
a.id    b.id    b.aid   c.id    c.bid
3       null    null    null    null
```

And now look at the join condition `b.id = c.bid` it's pretty clear that it will remove that row because the value of `b.id` is null due to the outer join between a and b and thus the inner join removes that row again.

You have to use an outer join for the join between b and c as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
  LEFT JOIN c ON b.id = c.bid
;
```

Comment: *shame on me* :) Thank you, that's it!

Comment: To be sincere, I have no idea if `ANSI_NULLS` were switched on where I worked before. They also used VB.NET siphoned data from ACCESS into the DB. So it's possible that I lived for years in a world where `NULL = NULL` without noticing it (at univ I learned very well that `NULL` is not equal to anything else).

Comment: @pid: I removed that part. Even with `ansi_nulls` set to off I don't get a different result

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be interpreted like this (note the brackets):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    a
    LEFT JOIN
    b
    ON a.id = b.aid
    )
    INNER JOIN c
    ON b.id = c.bid
```

Instead, you probably meant:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
    b
    INNER JOIN c
    ON b.id = c.bid
    )
    ON a.id = b.aid
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended. Thank you, the other answer shows how to obtain the result!